# How do I view a feed consisting of posts from multiple categories?

Tags: categories, rss

By default, my site's RSS feed URLs are in this format:

```
category/[category-name]/feed/
```

As far as I can tell, that doesn't allow me to view a feed using multiple categories. Is anyone aware of a simple workaround, or is this something I'll need to write myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this might help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-rss-feed-that-includes-multiple-categories

Comment: That looks great, although a) It would be useful to include that solution directly in the answer (but that's probably a whole meta discussion) b) The solution is perfect, EXCEPT for the fact that the feed's title (via wp_title_rss()?) is determined by the first category, which isn't really what I want. I think I'll probably just get it to read from $_GET, since I actually want my title to be completely unrelated to any category's title.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this plugin: [**Feed Wrangler**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-wrangler/) as it allows you to create your own custom feed but requires some modification of feed template files.

Here is an article listing 10 different external sites/services that can mix and blend feeds:

- [**10 Tools to Combine, Mix, Blend Multiple RSS Feeds**](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/10-tools-to-combine-mix-blend-multiple-rss-feeds/)

RSSMIX seems to come highly recommended it is even mentioned in the wordpress codex here:

- [**Customizing Feeds on WordPress' Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds)